# What are the Default $PATH Values?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

On Mac OS X, the default `$PATH` values are:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

What are the default values on Linux?

Comment: default path is defined in [config-top.h](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/config-top.h)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On a default Ubuntu desktop install `$PATH` is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

But in a minimal chroot environment created by `debootstrap`, `$PATH` only contains:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Answer (score 13):

Environment path values are stored in *.bashrc* file in ubuntu.

The system-wide PATH variable is defined in `/etc/environment`

Comment: Thanks -- I couldn't find where this file was actually sourced, but it appears to be included by PAM, in e.g. /etc/pam.d/login (and cron, su, etc)

Comment: Great. I had my $PATH variable messed up and I just had to run `source /etc/environment`

Answer (score 13):

`bash` will set `PATH` to a hard-coded default value if it's not set in the environment:

```
$ env -i bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
```

We can check that this value is indeed hard-coded, and not read from the environment or some file, using the `strings` utility:

```
$ strings /bin/bash | grep /usr/sbin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
```

However, I get a different result on my Arch Linux machine:

```
$ env -i bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

So, the default is chosen at the time the `bash` binary was built, which depends on the Linux distribution in use.

The `bash` man page [states](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/doc/bash.1?h=f188aa6a013e89d421e39354086eed513652b492#n2491):

> **PATH**
>
> The search path for commands.  It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands (see **COMMAND EXECUTION** below). A zero-length (null) directory name in the value of **PATH** indicates the current directory. A null directory name may appear as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon. The default path is system-dependent,
> and is set by the administrator who installs **bash**. A common value is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin`.

Here, "installs" likely refers to `make install` (as opposed to installing a pre-built binary using a package manager), so "administrator" would refer to the distribution vendor.

The "INVOCATION" section in the man page describes the startup process, which may affect the initial value of the variable.

Comment: This is the only answer that mentions the shell, and distributions. I stumbled upon the question because I'm sorting out PATH issues in ubuntu containers. And the "default path" will depend on the shell (bash, sh, etc.) and whether it's loaded interactively or not, and whether it's a login shell. It's not a simple answer. Kudos for mention of the hardcoded strings in the binary.

Comment: And on some other Linux distros they seem to rely on this behaviour! I did some digging on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and they do define a default path for csh, but not for bash. Crazy stuff!  (I realize this has nothing to do with Ubuntu, but neither does the original question...)

Answer (score 8):

There are path builtin the shells which is

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Then the default path for Ubuntu is:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which Linux your using, it might be different.  If you have a login to a linux already, just type 'env' to see your environment variables.

If you want to know how the PATH env variable is getting built, have a look at .bashrc and .bash_profile in your home directory.  If more curious, you can also look at /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/* (if exists) and manual for bash (man bash).

Answer (score 3):

There's an easy way to find out:

```
printenv
```

Or, more directly:

```
echo $PATH
```

But, if you're just looking for some quick info, Ubuntu typically sets the path to:

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:

For questions like this, you can usually dig up the answer by reading the [Bible](http://books.google.com/books?id=rsSlrQLB8-gC).

Comment: That's not always true because sometimes the PATH might appear messed up in this way. I'd look directly at `/etc/environment` as the ground truth.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical location seems to vary across distributions.  With Debian 10, the system-default PATH is defined in `/etc/login.defs`.  The default PATH for normal users is its `ENV_PATH` variable and the default for super-users is `ENV_SUPATH`.  These will be used for sessions that don't spawn shells (e.g. cron jobs)

Other defaults may be defined by the per-shell scripts, including:

- /etc/bash.bashrc
- /etc/csh.cshrc
- /etc/csh.login
- /etc/profile
- /etc/profile.d/*

Comment: What about /etc/environment?

Comment: As I wrote, it varies across distributions.

Answer (score 1):

To see the default path use what other mentioned in answers:

```
echo $PATH
```

To edit use:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

This default `PATH` variable are defined under `/etc/enviroment`.

Comment: That's not always true because sometimes the PATH might appear messed up in this way. I'd look directly at /etc/environment as the ground truth.