# Path error, Unable to Login in Ubuntu 20.04 Login Keep Looping

Tags: 20.04, login, loop-device

Suddenly, I am getting into very serious problem with the following error in the image.

I shut down my PC and when I started it again suddenly after login, it went into login loop and could not enter into the desktop. Then I logged in using tty3 `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F3`and after login I see the following error.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZf7g.jpg) i.stack.imgur.com/3CMnH.jpg

I tried all the approaches over the internet but it didn't work. Note: Form tty3 `startx` command works

Following are the paths set in the System:

`echo $PATH` `/home/muzamil/anaconda3/bin:/bin:/condabin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin`

and

`cat /etc/environment` `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:$PATH" JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_261 JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_261/jre`

Thanks

**Solution:**

It looks weird but somehow I managed to fix this issue. It seems that paths from `~/.profile` and `/etc/environment` could not read. I tried to set paths from `~/.profile` and `/etc/environment` into `~/.bashrc` manually and run `source ~/.bashrc`, it set the path permanently but could bot read when I login to the system (same loop).

After hours of search I found out [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/941995/3155305),
Hence setting the paths at the top in ~/.bashrc file before following line

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

worked for me. It looks like bash interactive mode could not run and could not read paths from `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

From the error you're getting it sounds like there is something wrong with your user's PATH environment variable (the value doesn't contain /usr/bin and /bin).

Would it be possible for you to run the following command (from your tty3) and post the output:

```
echo $PATH
```

This will print your current path environment variable.

It is also possible that your system-wide path environment variable is somehow mis-configured.  You can check that by running:

```
cat /etc/environment
```

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/386630/1066398)

Comment: Even when i set `/usr/bin` and `/bin` path to `bashrc` it still have the same error

Comment: Hi 
`echo $PATH` return this path `/home/muzamil/anaconda3/bin:/bin:/condabin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin`

and 
`cat /etc/environment` `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:$PATH" JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_261 JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_261/jre`