# Opening a piece of software from anywhere

Tags: software-installation, application-development, indicator, appmenu

I have a compiled program in a certain folder that I would like to access from anywhere without needing the write `./path/to/file/each/time/app_name`. For example, the app executable is installed in this `./path/to/file/each/time/app_name` path, and I would like to be able to open it by writing `app_name` in the command line, and nothing more than that. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script (as root) called `/usr/local/bin/app_name` and put this inside it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/file/app_name $@
```

Then make the script executable:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/app_name
```

Comment: Better also explain why and how that works. You may also want to complete the answer by adding another option, i.e. to place a symlink to the executable in `/usr/local/bin`. In addition, it is worthwhile mentioning the option to use ~/bin or ~/.local/bin if only the current user needs access - in that case, no root access is needed.

Comment: `~/.bin` and such are not in `$PATH` by default so that's a deeper rabbit hole. There are other problems with symlinks. This solution works everywhere regardless of those problems and also allows you to do more flexible things like add default arguments or run more complex composite commands.

Comment: .bin is automatically included in the path if it exist on Ubuntu, so  no rabitt hole there. There is more rabitt holes in trying to do everything as root. With symlinks, there will be no more problems than with your approach. If an app requires you to start in a specific folder or set an environment before, then indeed a wrapper script is the way to go.

Comment: Nope. The default path for 20.04 LTS is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: You must have a different linux version then, or you are using a different shell.

Comment: Nope. These are default `$PATH` values, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/386629/what-are-the-default-path-values

Comment: `~/bin` is added to PATH if and only if it exists (as vanadium says). You can find the code that adds it in `~/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias for your program in the `.bashrc` file.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

At the end of the file type the line:

```
alias app_name=/path/to/file/each/time/app_name
```

Then save (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

You will be able to use the alias in new Terminal windows you open.